# Whats language of init.rc in android?

Tags: android, c

i need to understand the format of init.rc

in init.rc there are so manny services. One of them is

```
service bootanim /system/bin/bootanimation
    user graphics
    group graphics
    disabled
    oneshot
```

here whats meaning of `disabled`,     `oneshot` for what purpose this all are here?

i have refer this [article](http://www.androidenea.com/2009/08/init-process-and-initrc.html) but not getting so much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://elinux.org/Android_Booting is probably a better reference.

There's also [`system/core/init/README.md`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) from the Android source tree.

Answer (score 3):

From the init/readme.txt in the Android source tree.

> disabled -    This service will not automatically start with its class. 
>   It must be explicitly started by name.
>
> oneshot -   Do not restart the service when it exits.

Answer (score 3):

> `disabled`
>    This service will not automatically start with its class. It must be explicitly started by name.
>
> `oneshot`
>    Do not restart the service when it exits.

Here is a reference you can use:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/README.md

Answer (score 2):

It is a configuration file for services loaded in <source_root>/system/core/init/init.c by <source_root>/system/core/init/init_parser.c. init_parser.c parses and loads appropriate services.