# About "init: untracked pid xxxx exited" in Genymotion

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, genymotion

Sometimes I see the following logcat output such as that below:

```
<3>[  283.152845] init: untracked pid 4217 exited
<3>[  283.162185] init: untracked pid 4078 exited
<3>[  283.173691] init: untracked pid 1504 exited
<3>[  283.177018] init: untracked pid 1468 exited
```

What is the meaning of the log of init: `untracked pid xxxx exited`?

Comment: have you overcome this log. can we disable and able to get command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

use logcat and read the huge log carefully. You might find the program that crashes all the time.

Comment: This is cause of killing init process. So we might find the root-cause of killing init process.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many different reasons, one of them is that android init trying to
initialize services specified by init.rc failed.

You can try to bisect the services started from init.rc first, and once you find
the errornous service, then try to fix the specific service start up errors, which
may be the kernel driver error, or android hal driver error, library fault, or
sometimes android framework error.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this message (modern version of which is "Untracked pid XXX exited with status YY") means that Android init sees a child process exit (that is, receives SIGCHLD signal and then gets its pid with `waitpid()`), but it can't associate that process with any of configured services (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905593/whats-language-of-init-rc-in-android) on Android init service configuration).

This in turn opens up a question of what can daemonize itself in Android environment and how to find it. But I don't think that I can answer that, the only suggestion that I have is getting root access and checking processes.